# DataGridView RowFilter double and CurrentCultureInfo issues

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I currently have a DGV populated by a DB Table with a column storing a double value (DB Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS). Whenever I trigger a rowfilter by textbox_changetext event I get a format exception, code as follows:

```
if (textBox4.Text != "" && textBox4.Text.Replace("*", "").Length > 0)
{
    filtertext += string.Format("[Esp (mm)]= {0} AND ", Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text));
}

private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        (dataGridView4.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filtertext;
            state = State.Pending;

        dataGridView4.Refresh();
        label13.Text = "Total de registros: " + dataGridView4.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        claMisc.MsgBox(err.ToString());
    }
}
```

My CurrentCultureInfo is based on a NumberDecimalSeparator="," and DGV seems to be loaded under this format, however "Convert.ToDouble" returns "." as DecimalSeparator. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The filter was triggering a EnterCell event with empty datagridview. The solution was this if:

```
public void event(sender, eventargs)
{
   if (dataGridView.Rows.Count>0 && dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count>0 && dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex<dataGridView.Rows.Count) continue...
}
```